# How do I make a simple button in liftweb

Tags: scala, button, lift

I am completely new to webprogramming, I never made anything that goes in that direction. But for some reason I now want to know how it works. Since I am familar with scala i tried the lift framework.

I want to create a Button that does nothing more than notifying the server that the button was pressed.

At the moment my button is:

```
<input type="submit" value="chat"/>
```

and the notification of the server works with

```
SHtml.hidden( makeRequest _ )
```

But somhow this feels very stupid. It works, and it looks like how I want it to look like. But creating a hidden form element, just because i cant bind a function to a button element feels so ... yea I can't find a better word than stupid.

```
SHtml.submitButton(makeRequest _)
```

Is also very strange. I can't give a name to it (why?) and the function is not called when pressed (why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you wrapped the XML/HTML template with a form attribute? Apart from that, `SHtml.submit("button name", makeRequest)` should usually work.

Have a look at [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-6.html#toc-Chapter-6).